# PHP json_decode on google app engine - invalide behavior

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am facing a strange issue with using php's json_decode on google app engine. For any string starting with a number, json_decode returns a response showing that it was a valid json string, while it was not. For example if I do json_decode('508'), it returns 508. If I do json_decode('2018-04-30'), it returns 2018.

Can this be a google app engine specific issue with running php' json_decode? because this just works fine in php when not running it on google app engine.

Comment: What are you actually json_decoding? Why would you JSON decode '508' or '2018-04-30'.... The values you have in your question are not JSON, so there's no need to json_decode them. Can you please supply more information?

Comment: I agree with MonkeyZeus here, what you got there just isn't json. it should be quoted. it's not really a php issue as far as one can tell.

Comment: Actually I have dynamic set of values. I need to check if any of these values are json, then json_decode them to be able to use as native php object / array. So I encouter such non-json values and when passsed to json_decode to check whether they are valid json or not, the check passes.

Answer (score 1):

**tl;dr**

`json_decode('2018-04-30')` is wrong and should be `json_decode('"2018-04-30"')`

*Something* is supplying bad JSON to your PHP.

---

**How to check for a bad JSON string**

```
$var = '2018-04-30';

// Note: $decoded_json will still be 2018 due to PHP's handling of string to int in this case but there will be a JSON error
$decoded_json = json_decode($var);

if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE)
{
    echo 'Good JSON!';
}
else
{
    echo 'Bad JSON: '.json_last_error_msg();

    // We can try wrapping the $var in double quotes to try and force good JSON since the data source is untrusted
    $decoded_json = json_decode('"'.$var.'"');

    if(json_last_error() === JSON_ERROR_NONE)
    {
        echo 'Fixable JSON!';
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'Really bad JSON: '.json_last_error_msg();
    }
}
```

---

`json_decode('2018-04-30')` gives `2018` because `2018-04-30` is unquoted and is converted to an integer to the best of PHP's ability. Try this to get a better grasp of PHP's behavior:

```
echo (int)'2018-04-30';
```

Comment: Thanks. That might stand true but what if I have dynamic set of values and I need to check whether a specific value is valid json or not? so if '2018-04-30' was a variable, I also checked by doing json_decode((string)$var) and it didn't work either. Do I really need to supply double quotes explicitly ?